# How to make an object full of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to make a structure like this:

```
var myThings = {
    thing1: {
        ['24-04-12', '90'],
        ['25-04-12', '90'],
        ['26-04-12', '90']
    },
    thing2: {
        ['24-04-12', '10'],
        ['25-04-12', '30'],
        ['26-04-12', '210']
    }
}
```

(There are 4 things, hardcoded).

The arrays in each object will be added in a loop, so my code looks like this:

```
var myThings = {"thing1":{}, "thing2":{}};
```

I then can't work out how to push my arrays into the object.

Am I being dumb, or is this not the way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not the way to do it. You can't have "loose" arrays in an object. You should use an array instead.

Comment: How can I structure it - later I want to loop through the thing1,thing2 etc and read out the date and prices from the internal arrays. What structure would you use?

Comment: An array of arrays: `var myThings = {"thing1":[], "thing2":[]};`

Comment: Just use an array: `thing1: []`. Add more stuff there with `myThings.thing1.push( [ another, array ] )` and retrieve them by looping through the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an `Array` instead an `Object` there. Like

```
var myThings = {
    thing1: [
        ['24-04-12', '90'],
        ['25-04-12', '90'],
        ['26-04-12', '90']
    ],
    thing2: [
        ['24-04-12', '10'],
        ['25-04-12', '30'],
        ['26-04-12', '210']
    ]
}
```

Now since `thing1` and `thing2` are `Arrays` you can just use `Array.prototype.push` to push new `Arrays` into that `Array`.

```
Object.keys( myThings ).forEach(function( thing ) {
    myThings[ thing ].push( ['01-01-12', '42'] );
});
```

That code would add `['01-01-12', '42']` to all current `things` in that object.

<sup>Disclaimer: The above code contains ES5. You need a browser which supports that or a Shim to emulate</sup>

Comment: Which bit is ES5 - the `keys` method?

Comment: @RichBradshaw: `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.forEach`. There are lots of shims available which emulate that methods for pretty old'ish browser. Also, its very simple to write in ES3 aswell.

Comment: What do I need to read to see why I can't put the arrays in an object? Seems I'm missing a bit of fundamn

Comment: @Rich: Objects are basically `key => value` pairs. In your case, you would not have a key: `{[...], [...]}`. How do you expect to access the arrays? If you want to read up on the basics, have a look at the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Answer (score 3):

I'd do:

```
//create your array dynamically
var array1 = [['24-04-12', '90'],
        ['25-04-12', '90'],
        ['26-04-12', '90'] ];

var myThings = {
    thing1: array1
        ,
    thing2: array1
}
```

This way, the properties of your object are arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your inner items being objects, you should make them arrays. Objects must exist in key-value pairs, which does not make sense for your usage. Arrays are also key-value pairs, but the key is simply the index number.

```
var myThings = {
    thing1: [ // thing1 is now an array of arrays
        ['24-04-12', '90'],
        ['25-04-12', '90'],
        ['26-04-12', '90']
    ],
    thing2: [ // thing2 is now an array of arrays
        ['24-04-12', '10'],
        ['25-04-12', '30'],
        ['26-04-12', '210']
    ]
}; // don't forget this semicolon...
```

You would then access the inner-most values like this:

```
myThings.thing1[0][1]; // gives you back '90'
myThings.thing2[2][0]; // gives you back '210'
```

If you want to iterate over the `myThings` object, use a [for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). If you want to iterate over any of the interior arrays, use a [regular for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). As long as you [do NOT use for...in on the arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays) :)